# What is this plant? It’s very fast growing

Tags: identification

I need help identifying this plant- can’t seem to find out what it is online.

It’s growing out of a dead stump of another bush. It’s grown really quickly as the stump it’s growing out of was cut down about 2 months ago and it’s now about 2 foot tall

[image]

Comment: Fairly normal for suckers with the root system of an entire tree supporting them to grow quickly when the tree is cut down. So it's virtually certain to be the same type of tree (or bush) that was cut.

Comment: Elm? Sumac? Great shine.

Comment: Not elm, nor sumac.

Comment: Given the groups of 9 pinnate leaves, and opposing branches, quite possibly an ash tree.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I agree with you, and the 'stump' is also hinting at Ash :-(.  http://www.emeraldashborer.info/documents/E-2942.pdf